# Python tkinter - How to get the value of Optionmenu created by loop in a list?

Tags: python, tkinter, optionmenu

I would like that when the user choose an item in one of the Optionmenus, the chosen value will be saved to a **specific** position in a list (*listbox_list*). The Optionmenu are created by a Loop.

I tried the code below but it doesn't work.

If the user choose "Calc" in the third Optionmenu, so the value in listbox_list[2] will be adapted with "Calc".

How can I do ?

```
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

head_list=('Calc','Capacity','Speed','Weight')
listbox_list=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("800x600")

def printa():
    print(listbox_list[1].get()) -- EDIT : SOLUTION I FOUND


boutonlaunch=Button(fenetre,text="Launch",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=printa)
boutonlaunch.pack(side=LEFT)

ay=0
i_num=0
for x in range(21):
    cadre1=Frame(fenetre)
    cadre1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    cadre=Frame(cadre1)
    cadre.pack()
    
    index_label=Label(cadre, width=5,text=i_num)
    index_label.pack(side=LEFT)
    
    var_entry=StringVar()
    my_entry=Entry(cadre,textvariable=var_entry, bd=5)
    my_entry.pack(side=LEFT)
    
    value_inside = StringVar()
    value_inside.set("Select an Option")
    listbox = OptionMenu(cadre, value_inside, *head_list, command=lambda _:list_add)
    listbox.config(width=20)
    listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
    listbox_list[i_num]=value_inside #--- EDIT : SOLUTION I FOUND
    i_num+=1
    
fenetre.mainloop()

os.system('pause')
```

Thank you !

**EDIT SOLUTION:**
My Error was listbox_list[i_num]=value_inside.get() , we just need listbox_list[i_num]=value_inside (without the get()) ***to add to the list***. Then we want to call the specific value, we need the .get().

Comment: You know that each time the `for` loop runs it creates a new variable for `var_entry` so when you call `list_add` it uses the last definition of `var_entry`. Try adding all of the `var_entry`s in a list

Comment: I add     listbox_list[i_num]=value_inside.get() under listbox.pack(side=LEFT) but how can I modify the list. 
The def list_add doesn't replace the value in the list as wished.

Comment: I fount the solution and added it directly in the code !

Comment: line 39, in <lambda>
    listbox = OptionMenu(cadre, value_inside, *head_list, command=lambda _:list_add)
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'list_add' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

My Error was `listbox_list[i_num] = value_inside.get()`: I just need `listbox_list[i_num] = value_inside` (without the `get()`) to add to the list. Then we want to call the specific value, we need the `.get()`.

```py
import os
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter.messagebox import showinfo

head_list=('Calc','Capacity','Speed','Weight')
listbox_list=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]


fenetre=Tk()
fenetre.geometry("800x600")

def printa():
    print(listbox_list[1].get()) # <- HERE


boutonlaunch=Button(fenetre,text="Launch",width=15,height=1,bg="white",bd=5, command=printa)
boutonlaunch.pack(side=LEFT)

ay=0
i_num=0
for x in range(21):
    cadre1=Frame(fenetre)
    cadre1.pack(side=TOP,anchor=NW)
    cadre=Frame(cadre1)
    cadre.pack()
    
    index_label=Label(cadre, width=5,text=i_num)
    index_label.pack(side=LEFT)
    
    var_entry=StringVar()
    my_entry=Entry(cadre,textvariable=var_entry, bd=5)
    my_entry.pack(side=LEFT)
    
    value_inside = StringVar()
    value_inside.set("Select an Option")
    listbox = OptionMenu(cadre, value_inside, *head_list, command=lambda _:list_add)
    listbox.config(width=20)
    listbox.pack(side=LEFT)
    listbox_list[i_num]=value_inside # <- HERE
    i_num+=1
    
fenetre.mainloop()

os.system('pause')
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/67195722/2) to the question [Python tkinter - How to get the value of Optionmenu created by loop in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195722/python-tkinter-how-to-get-the-value-of-optionmenu-created-by-loop-in-a-list) by the OP [Meriole](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15508182/meriole) under CC BY-SA 4.0.</sub>

Comment: line 39, in <lambda>
    listbox = OptionMenu(cadre, value_inside, *head_list, command=lambda _:list_add)
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^
NameError: name 'list_add' is not defined